# Pairup with Tmux and Ngrok

Tags: pair-programming, ngrok

I'm having a little trouble getting my client to connect. I'm able to have ngrok tell me the port, but when I go to the client and execute:

```
ssh pairup@ngrok.com -p 57613
```

I get

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Any ideas why this is happening? I'm on a Mac, and I followed these steps: https://www.adaptivelab.com/blog/pair-programming-with-tmux/

Thanks a lot for your time

Answer (score 3):

It could be that you don't have the ssh server installed on the machine you're running ngrok, so, the connection is refused.

To install it just type the following in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```